# Range function and list

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, range

So, I'm self teaching myself a bit about python and I've been reading about "range" for about 2 days now, but i can't seem to figure out on how to solve this:

I'll like to write a program that prints out a list of even numbers in a given range after asking some questions...

The questions are:

- How many numbers are in the list
- The lowest value
- The highest value

So i started like this:

```
def main():

    numbers = int(input("How many numbers are in the list: "))
    lowest = int(input("Please enter the lowest range value to start with: "))
    highest = int(input("Please enter the highest range value to end with: "))

    for i in range (lowest, highest+2, 2):
        print (i)

main ()
```

I know this is wrong, the numbers variable does nothing since i did not assign it to do anything. and a bunch of other stuff perhaps

Essentially what I would like for the program to do is this:

- Say the numbers variable enter is 6
- Lowest variable enter is 2
- Highest is 12

Print out should be 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 - for a total of 6 numbers entered staring from the lowest to the highest value selected.

On the same token, if the info enter is

- Numbers: 5
- Lowest: 2
- Highest: 12

I'll like some error to return since the user surpass the numbers length since the selection was 5.

Comment: what's the error that you get? What version of python are you running?

Comment: No error - I'm working with ver 3.2

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for the purpose you describe.

Comment: The numbers variable is doing nothing really - I'll like to use that variable as the insert point as to how many numbers to print

Comment: The first two questions are enough the generate the desired output from my understanding, why would you ask for the highest number and return an error if it's not the right one?

Comment: @CoDEmanX, This looks like an "I want to learn how to do this" type of question.

Comment: If it's about to learn coding frustrating programs... \*sarcasm\*

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():

    numbers = int(input("How many numbers are in the list "))
    lowest = int(input("Please enter the lowest range value to start with: "))
    highest = int(input("Please enter the highest range value to end with "))
    if (highest+2 - lowest)/2 == numbers:
        for i in range (lowest,highest+2,2 ):
            print (i)
    else:
        print ('no coinciden los numeros, vuelve a intentarlo')

main ()
```

This helps?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw an error when the user enters inconsistent input (ie the number requested does not match the expected number in the range), you can do an explicit check and `exit` with an error if the check does not pass.

```
from sys import exit

def main():
    numbers = int(input("How many numbers are in the list "))
    lowest = int(input("Please enter the lowest range value to start with: "))
    highest = int(input("Please enter the highest range value to end with "))

    if len(range (lowest,highest+2,2 )) != numbers:
       print("The number of numbers requested is unexpected!")
       exit(1)
    for i in range (lowest,highest+2,2 ):
        print (i)

main ()
```

Comment: You might raise an exception (like a `ValueError`) rather than printing an error message and calling `exit`. That would (in theory) allow calling code to catch the exception and do something else if they wanted.

Comment: @Blckknght, Good point. I was trying to show him how to detect the error, but I'll add that.

Comment: Although i served the purpose - it returned a valueError. looking more for a more gentle error such as " Sorry, numbers selected overlap" or something as such

Comment: In that case, I will leave it simple.

Comment: Thanks @merlin2011 - certainly got what i needed This place is f-ing awesome!

Comment: @juanserrano you are welcome.  Please mark this add the accepted answer if it resolved your question.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're interested in a cryptic version, here it is:

```
limit = 4
min_val = 3
max_val = 22

# output: 4, 6, 8, 10    
print(
    ", ".join(
        str(j) for i, j in
            enumerate(
                range(
                    min_val + (0 if min_val % 2 == 0 else 1),
                    max_val + 2,
                    2
                )
            )
        if i < limit
    )
)
```

It can be golf'd to a single line:

```
print(", ".join(str(j)for i,j in enumerate(range(min_val+(0if min_val%2==0 else 1),max_val+2,2))if i<limit))
```

It starts at `min_val` (+1 if it's an odd number, making it even) and ends at `max_val`, unless the maximum count `limit` is reached earlier. A generator expression is used for the numbers and joined to a string, with the elements separated by `,` .

Less cryptic using a regular for-loop:

```
limit = 4
min_val = 3
max_val = 22

if min_val % 2 != 0:
    min_val += 1

for i, j in enumerate(range(min_val, max_val + 2, 2)):
    if i >= limit:
        break
    print(j)
```